# NGINX Docker container won't stay running?

Tags: docker, nginx

I've Googled and looked thru several answers on SO but nothing I'm trying seems to work

I have a Dockerfile which downloads PHP 7 (cli+fpm) and installs NGINX as a final step with this command in attempt to keep the container running:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install nginx

CMD ["service","nginx", "start", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

What am I not understanding about containers? I previously used the PHP binary itself as the web server, the final command would fire the built int server and the container stayed running and everything worked great.

NGINX exists with code 0?

Thoughts?

Comment: What do the logs for NGINX say? Is anything written to standard out?

Comment: Try not to bundle too much into a single container. Look up some [Docker Compose LEMP stacks](https://github.com/stevenliebregt/docker-compose-lemp-stack)

Comment: Nothing being logged to console, I can't remote into the container to check the logs, it exists with code 0

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

When you run  `service nginx start`, the command is responsible to `only start` the service. After starting `nginx` the command finishes its job successfully, with exit code 0.

As a result the container exits, since it's main process exited

You can see this by running

```
docker logs container_name
```

The logs will end with following line

```
Starting nginx: nginx.
```

Instead, if you run the command proposed it will iniate the nginx process without exiting